# Google Calendar API doesn't return all events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-calendar-api

I integrated the google API in my react project. I have about 300 Entries in my calendar but I only receive about 180 entries.

What is my Mistake?

Tank you!

```
const getEvents = async () => {
    function start() {
        gapi.client
            .init({
                apiKey: "MyKey",
            })
            .then(function () {
                return gapi.client.request({
                    path: `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/"myMail"/events`,
                });
            })
            .then((response) => {
                let events = response.result.items;
                console.log(events);
                setEventObject(events);
            });
    }
    gapi.load("client", start);
};
```

UPDATE
This doesn't work. It seems like the additional parameters has no impact of the request...

```
const getEvents = () => {
    function start() {
        gapi.client
            .init({
                apiKey: "myKey",
            })
            .then(function () {
                return gapi.client.request({
                    path: `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/"myMail"/events`,
                    maxResults: 2500,
                    showDeleted: true,
                });
            })
            .then((response) => {
                let events = response.result.items;
                console.log(events);
                setEventObject(events);
            });
    }
    gapi.load("client", start);
};
```

Comment: In your situation, when `maxResults=2500&showDeleted=true` is used to the query parameter, what result will you obtain? Because the default value of `maxResults` is `250`. But in your question, `180` events are retrieved from `300` events. So I thought `showDeleted` might be also required. Or, how about using `nextPageToken`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: You understood my question. But unfortunately this seems not to be the solution. Stil 181 results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your passing your parameters the wrong way through the request. [Checkout the google github](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/reference.md#----gapiclientrequestargs--)

You need to pass the `params` URL params in key-value pair form.

```
return gapi.client.request({
    path: `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/"myMail"/events`,
    params: { maxResults: 2500, showDeleted: true }
});
```

Comment: @jansemrau Im guessing that worked out for you?